# install rpm on macOS

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I'm just writing code in vscode and macOS, if I write this code I have error , how can I solve this  if I write code to vscode (terminal) { rpm I express monogoose pjs } then

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/monoogoose - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'monoogoose@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa0U4.png)

I need a server to macOS , I need install node.js and node.js packages

Comment: There is a lot of typos in your question. I assume that you're looking for 'mongoose' package. `npm install express mongoose ejs` command should work. In some cases on macOS, you could need to use 'sudo' but you should try without it before.